# Correct way to POST JSON data from Android to PHP

Tags: php, android, json, http-headers, http-post

I have seen many tutorials and questions using the following method to send JSON object to PHP  from Android. For example [this wordpress blog](http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/the-simplest-way-to-post-parameters-between-android-and-php/), [this codeproject tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php) and some answers on stackoverflow [like these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779773/reading-json-object-sent-from-android-in-php).

All of these tutorials and answers use **HTTP header** to send data(body) to PHP like this.

```
....
// Post the data:
httppost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
....
```

As a programmer we all know that **headers are not meant to carry data(body)**. Headers should only carry metadata.

So, is there a correct way to send JSON data to PHP from Android which does not involve setting data in header?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use nativ lib without Volley, here is dummy with HttpClient:

```
httpClient = createHttpClient();

//You wanna use POST method.
mPost = new HttpPost(_urlStr);

//Head
mPost.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"));

//Body
((HttpPost) mPost).setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonText));

//Do it.
client.execute(mPost);
```

Try to use Volley: https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples/blob/master/src/com/github/volley_examples/Act_SimpleRequest.java

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [simple tutorial](https://github.com/znq/Simple-HTTP-Client/tree/master/src/com/devstream/http) to send and receive JSON objects in Android.